# How to override a vm DNS servers?

Tags: linux, dns, virtual-machine, network-interface, networkmanager

I'm running a CentOS 7 Virtual machine and it's picking up the DNS nameservers from my Fedora 27 system via DHCP I believe. I am trying to change the DNS nameserver in `/etc/resolv.conf` to google name servers. It's different on my fedora 27, when I do that and do `systemctl restart network` it goes back to the same nameservers on the fedora 27.

Is there a way to override that?

I believe I have to do something in `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/`

I am connected via ethernet `enp0s3` on the vm and of course bridged on `virbr0`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The network interface of the VM is configured to accept DNS from `dhcp` only. Change the interface settings.

Network interface configuration files are in `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/`.

Say it's a kvm vps and the network interface is eth0. Edit the file `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifconfig-eth0` and add the following for Google's IPv4 nameserver

```
PEERDNS=no
DNS1=8.8.8.8
DNS2=8.8.4.4
```

Then restart networking as follows

```
sudo service network restart
```

You may use any other nameserver.

The above mentioned nameservers will be added in `resolve.conf` and `PEERDNS=no` directive will stop `dhcp` from altering nameserver.

**Another way** out is making `resolv.conf` read only even for root as follows

```
chattr +i /etc/resolv.conf
```

If you want to edit the file latter use `chattr -i /etc/resolv.conf` before editing.

**P.S.** `PEERDNS=no` works only with RHEL based system including RHEL, CentOS and Fedora.

Comment: Using systemd to restart the network service: `sudo systemctl restart network.service`

Comment: That's fine. You can use either `systemctl` or `service`. `systemctl` is newer implementation in Fedora like systems. `service` is obsolete and redirect to `systemctl`. I use service because it's more generic.